# Why are there extra td cells in my table when using angular ng-repeat in my directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to figure out why there are extra empty td cells in the table rows when I am using angular to help me generate a dynamic html table.

How do I get rid of the extra td cells happening on each row?
Do I have to transclude something in my angular directive?

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

var periods = [{
  "abbreviation": "AM",
  "name": "Homeroom AM",
  "sort": 1
}, {
  "abbreviation": "PM",
  "name": "Homeroom PM",
  "sort": 2
}]

var r = [
  [{
    "$id": "1",
    "Abbreviation": "AM",
    "AttendanceCode": "AU",
    "AttendanceDate": "2016-06-27T00:00:00",
    "CustomNumber": "1",
    "Firstname": "Simon",
    "Lastname": "Birch",
    "CustomId": "152560",
    "PeriodNumber": "1",
    "PeriodSortOrder": 1,
    "LastFirst": "Birch, Simon",
    "GradeLevel": "A"
  }],
  [{
    "$id": "2",
    "Abbreviation": "PM",
    "AttendanceCode": "VA",
    "AttendanceDate": "2016-06-27T00:00:00",
    "CustomNumber": "2",
    "Firstname": "Simon",
    "Lastname": "Cloisvern",
    "CustomId": "179659",
    "PeriodNumber": "2",
    "PeriodSortOrder": 2,
    "LastFirst": "Cloisvern, Simon Ralph",
    "GradeLevel": "B"
  }],
  [{
    "$id": "3",
    "Abbreviation": "AM",
    "AttendanceCode": "AU",
    "AttendanceDate": "2016-06-27T00:00:00",
    "CustomNumber": "3",
    "Firstname": "Nadia",
    "Lastname": "Clukase",
    "CustomId": "157741",
    "PeriodNumber": "1",
    "PeriodSortOrder": 1,
    "LastFirst": "Clukase, Nadia",
    "GradeLevel": "C"
  }],
  [{
    "$id": "4",
    "Abbreviation": "AM",
    "AttendanceCode": "EA",
    "AttendanceDate": "2016-06-27T00:00:00",
    "CustomNumber": "4",
    "Firstname": "Pauline",
    "Lastname": "Cuzzic",
    "CustomId": "70505",
    "PeriodNumber": "1",
    "PeriodSortOrder": 1,
    "LastFirst": "Cuzzic, Pauline",
    "GradeLevel": "D"
  }, {
    "$id": "5",
    "Abbreviation": "PM",
    "AttendanceCode": "EA",
    "AttendanceDate": "2016-06-27T00:00:00",
    "CustomNumber": "4",
    "Firstname": "Pauline",
    "Lastname": "Cuzzic",
    "CustomId": "70505",
    "PeriodNumber": "2",
    "PeriodSortOrder": 2,
    "LastFirst": "Cuzzic, Pauline",
    "GradeLevel": "D"
  }]
]

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.periods = periods;
  $scope.records = r;
  //$log.info('this is some info');
}).directive('item', function($compile, $log) {
  function createTDElement(column) {
    var tableCell = angular.element('<td period="' + column + '"></td>');
    return tableCell;
  }

  function render(element, scope) {
    var column, html, i;
    for (i = 0; i < scope.periods.length; i++) {
      column = scope.periods[i];
      html = $compile(createTDElement(column.abbreviation))(scope);
      element.find('td:last').after(html);
    }
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      item: "=",
      periods: "="
    },
    compile: function() {
      return function(scope, element) {
        render(element, scope);
      }
    }
  }

}).directive('period', ['$compile', '$log', function ($compile, $log) {
        return {
            scope: {
                period: "@"
            },
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '{{replaceValue}}',
            controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
              angular.forEach($scope.$parent.item, function (item) {
                    if ($scope.period === item.Abbreviation)
                    {
                        $scope.replaceValue = item.AttendanceCode;
                        return $scope.replaceValue;
                    } 
                });
            }]
        }
    }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@1.9.1" data-semver="1.9.1" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel panel-warning" ng-app="test" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">Hello Plunker! Building dynamic table, placing column value in correct table cell</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <table id="attendance" class="table table-condensed" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Student</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
                <th ng-repeat="period in periods">
                  {{period.abbreviation}}
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-show="periods">
              <tr ng-repeat="d in records" item="d" periods="periods">
                <td>{{d[0].LastFirst}}</td>
                <td>{{d[0].AttendanceDate|date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                <td>{{d[0].GradeLevel}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="p in periods"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have an `ng-repeat` of `periods` and a directive that also loops over them to create cells

Comment: Remove <td ng-repeat="p in periods"></td> and it will work fine - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OXzRVJ

Comment: That did the trick, been staring at this for too long! (Awesome!)